# New HDD and SSD

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am using Ubuntu 16.10. I tried installing 16.04, but I had the no signal input issue with that. I have a new HDD (1TB WD Black), a new SSD (Samsung 850 EVO 250GB) and my old storage HDD (1TB WD Green).

I've had a lot of problems with installing the OS, sometimes because of bugs, sometimes because of my lack of knowledge.

I'm not familiar with mount points and I think I’ve done something wrong and I can't find the solution online. During installation I made a 20GB partition on my new black HDD for the `/` mounting point, a 20GB partition of SWAP also on my black HDD and a 10GB partition for EFI also on the black HDD, the rest of the space on the Black HDD I made the `/home` mountpoint. The space on the SSD I made one whole partition with no mountpoint and I didn't do anything to the WD Green HDD.

I'm sure it's not optimal, but it got my system running. When I look at my storage specs I see the old WD Green HDD showing up as "1TB Volume" and what I believe is the `/` partition I made showing up as "Computer" with a max size of 19.5 GB, but when I go inside it's folders I see the Home folder with a free space of 895GB. I don't see the SSD either.

What am I doing wrong/not doing? Also how do I select where to install a new program? I’m a bit rusty at Linux.

I am running a completely new install running a system build hours ago. No software is installed yet,

```
NAME   TYPE MODEL            FSTYPE LABEL   SIZE MOUNTPOINT
sdb    disk WDC WD1003FZEX-0              931.5G 
├─sdb4 part                  ext4           892G /home
├─sdb2 part                  vfat           1.9G /boot/efi
├─sdb3 part                  ext4          18.6G /
└─sdb1 part                  swap          19.1G [SWAP]
sdc    disk WDC WD10EZRX-00L              931.5G 
└─sdc1 part                  ntfs         931.5G /media/sparrow/827A97AD7A979D0B
sda    disk Samsung SSD 850               232.9G 
└─sda1 part                  ext4         232.9G /hs
```

Comment: I can't get it organized..
SDA is the SSD, SDB is the Black HDD' SDC is the Green HDD

Comment: You can format text as a code listing if you either 1) select it and press the `{}` button in the editor toolbar or 2) enclose it between `<pre>` and `</pre>`. You can delete your old comments that have since been moved to the body of your question or otherwise became obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from small inaccuracies most of how you describe your intended partition set-up is actually the way you want it. The only difference I can see is the size of the EFI partition (actually ~2 GB instead of the intended 20 GB, though 2 should be more than enough; 100–250 MB are more typical).

In addition to that, in the output of `lsblk` you can see two other file systems that happen to be "mounted":

- `/dev/sdc1` is the sole partition of a "WD10EZRX" drive (a "WD Green" series model) and mounted at `/media/sparrow/827A97AD7A979D0B`. The mountpoint path suggests that it was mounted through a file manager or something like Gnome Disks.
- `/dev/sda1` is the sole partition of a "Samsung SSD 850" drive and mounted at `/hs`, which suggests that is mounted manually or through a deliberately created entry in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Ok, so i found GParted and saw how it is, 19.07 swap, 1.86 efi,, 18.63 for the OS, and 891.95 "/home", all working good, i just didn;t read the os right.
but the SSD is not, it is showing up in the GParted and in the file explorer but when i try to move something to it it says i'm not authorized or something like that, any help on that maybe?

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.